# Copy single row from multidimensional array into new one dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to copy a specific row from a multidimensional array to a new one dimensional array that can be used somewhere else in my code.

Input:

Multidimensional array[3,3]:

```
33 300 500,
56 354 516,
65 654 489,
```

Required output:

Single Dimension Array (second line)

```
56 354 516
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies.  have to apologise, I only realized now, I over siplified the question, I should have been more exact.  My multidimensional array contains "double" values.  Sorry, still new to c#.  You may edit the question to suit the question better.

Comment: I don't think array containing double, string or int will matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var source = new int[3, 3]
{
    { 33, 300, 500 },
    { 56, 354, 516 },
    { 65, 654, 489 }
};
// initialize destination array with expected length
var dest = new int[source.GetLength(1)];

// define row number
var rowNumber = 1;

// copy elemements to destination array
for (int i = 0; i < source.GetLength(1); i++)
{
    dest[i] = (int) source.GetValue(rowNumber, i);
}
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for the help, do you mind if I edit the question?  I like your solution, however I cant get it to work for "double" values.

Comment: @Crysthius What's the problem? Just change all `int` lines to the `double`: `int[3, 3] -> double[3, 3]`, `new int[source.GetLength(1)]; -> new double[source.GetLength(1)];`, `(int) source.GetValue(rowNumber, i); -> (double) source.GetValue(rowNumber, i);`

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for the help, it worked. Kind Regards

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where the `Buffer.BlockCopy` may come handy:

```
int[,] original = new int[3, 3]
{
    { 33, 300, 500 },
    { 56, 354, 516 },
    { 65, 654, 489 }
};

int[] target = new int[3];
int rowIndex = 1; //get the row you want to extract your data from (start from 0)
int columnNo = original.GetLength(1); //get the number of column
Buffer.BlockCopy(original, rowIndex * columnNo * sizeof(int), target, 0, columnNo * sizeof(int));
```

You will get in your `target`:

```
56, 354, 516
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
        int[][] arrayComplex = {new[] {33, 300, 500},new []{56, 354, 516}, new []{65, 654, 489}};
        int[] arraySingle = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayComplex[1].Length; i++)
        {
            arraySingle[i] = arrayComplex[1][i];
        }

        foreach (var i in arraySingle)
        {
            Console.Write(i + "  ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 2.1 and later, you can use [`MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<T>(T, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createspan) method to create a linear Span from a multidimensional array, then use [`Span<T>.CopyTo(Span<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.copyto) method to copy the required data into or from the multidimensional array.

```cs
int[,] table =
{
    { 33, 300, 500 },
    { 56, 354, 516 },
    { 65, 654, 489 }
};

int[] ints1 = new int[3];
int[] ints2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var tableSpan = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref table[0, 0], table.Length);
// tableSpan is linear here: [33, 300, 500, 56, 354, 516, 65, 654, 489]

tableSpan.Slice(3, ints1.Length).CopyTo(ints1);
// ints1 is now: [56, 354, 516]

ints2.AsSpan().CopyTo(tableSpan.Slice(3, ints2.Length));
// table is now:
// {
//     { 33, 300, 500 },
//     { 1, 2, 3 },
//     { 4, 654, 489 }
// }
```